# Using where statements in do notation

Tags: haskell

Is there some way to use where statements in do notation without inconveniences:

```
x = do
  putStrLn "Enter file name"
  fileName  <- getLine
  putStrLn "Enter file extension"
  fileExt   <- getLine
  doIO $ fileName ++ "." ++ fileExt
  doSomeMoreIO $ fileName ++ "." ++ fileExt
```

It would be nice to have `where file = fileName ++ "." ++ fileExt`. Is there some way to do it?

I guess one way would be to have `file <- return $ fileName ++ "." ++ fileExt`, but this feels kind of weird, because I'm mixing business logic with convenience of writing.

Comment: Use a `let file = ...` line inside the `do` instead. `where` can not access the bindings like `fileName`.

Comment: You may also like [(<.>)](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/filepath-1.4.1.2/docs/System-FilePath-Posix.html#v:-60-.-62-).

Comment: I think it would be a really nice feature if a `where` clause could be used in this way with a `do` block. As it is I sometimes need to choose between creating a big `let` statement inline, or move a chunk of code into the `where` clause with a bunch of parameters which will just be bound to the same names and values in the `do` block. Both make the code more difficult to understand.

Comment: @jberryman yeah I have that same experience.  Though there are a bunch of difficult questions in the corner cases, which, when I put on my language design hat, I have no idea how to answer.

Answer (score 9):

`where`, no. `let`, yes:

```
x = do
  putStrLn "Enter file name"
  fileName  <- getLine
  putStrLn "Enter file extension"
  fileExt   <- getLine
  let file = fileName ++ "." ++ fileExt
  doIO file
  doSomeMoreIO file
```

Answer (score 2):

`let` is the most straightforward way, but another option may be to use a separate function:

```
x = do
  putStrLn "Enter file name"
  fileName  <- getLine
  putStrLn "Enter file extension"
  fileExt   <- getLine
  doFileIO $ fileName ++ "." ++ fileExt
  where
     doFileIO file = do
        doIO file
        doSomeMoreIO file
```

Depending on specific circumstances, this option may be preferable due to increased readability.